# jQuery Draggable - I can't resizing a div during the dragging?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g2HTV/1/) code :

## HTML

```
<div class="draggable_container">
    <div id="draggable_1" class="draggable">
        <div class="exp"><!-- --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.draggable_container
{
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    width:140px;
}

.draggable
{
    height:132px;
    width:130px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:5px solid #000000;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        draggedElement = $(ui.helper.context);
        distanzaTop = draggedElement.css('top').substring(0, (draggedElement.css('top').length - 2));

        if (distanzaTop < 20) {
            draggedElement.css('height', '132px');

        } else if (distanzaTop >= 20 && distanzaTop < 80) {
            draggedElement.css('height', '120px');

        } else if (distanzaTop >= 80 && distanzaTop < 140) {
            draggedElement.css('height', '86px');

        } else if (distanzaTop >= 140 && distanzaTop < 200) {
            draggedElement.css('height', '68px');

        } else if (distanzaTop >= 200) {
            draggedElement.css('height', '60px');
        }
    }    
});
```

So, what I done is resing the draggable div scrolling up/down with mouse. The problem is (as you can see) that I can't go to the bottom with a single movement. The div is blocking during the way...and I need to reselect it and move again to the bottom.

Curious : from the bottom to the top it works perfectly; from the top to the bottom it will block...

Why? And how can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the conditions starting with the largest value (200) towards the smallest:

```
if (distanzaTop < 20) {
    draggedElement.css('height', '132px');
} else if (distanzaTop >= 200) {
    draggedElement.css('height', '60px');
} else if (distanzaTop >= 140 && distanzaTop < 200) {
draggedElement.css('height', '68px');
} else if (distanzaTop >= 80 && distanzaTop < 140) {
draggedElement.css('height', '86px');
} else if (distanzaTop >= 20 && distanzaTop < 80) {
    draggedElement.css('height', '120px');
}
```